# Convert Received date time to local timezone time Android

Tags: android, time, timezone

Good day.I am building an chat application.For purpose i decided to put a date of message had been sent.No wounder that in different countries the date must show different.For example let's take 2 different countries and assume the difference between them are 2 hours.CountryX and CountryY.The user send message from CountryX which time is lets say 15:00.I am saving this on server with exact timezone time as user sent,exactly 15:00 as CountryX.Second user receives the message in CountryY which is more  in 2 hours from CountryX,so basically The time which I MUST show in CountryY must be 17:00.This is the issue.How can i convert an already received time with known timezone to local in order to show correct?I did google a lot but all i came up,were solutions where you would simply just get an time for exact country,and not convert the CountryX sent Time to CountryY local time to show it correctly in CountryY.Please can you provide an help?Thank you very much beforehand.

Comment: Check out lib called : PrettyTime its suits for Chats and local time zone

Comment: ok will chec now see what it will give

Comment: seems i can not find the needed methods

Comment: For this scenario, all you need is UTC.

Answer (score -1):

For everyone suffering because of this.I have ended up creating my own class with my own logic and it works flawlessly and as an extra bonus couple of handy methods with time

```
public class Time {
    public static String getCurrentTime() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        String finalFormat = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
        if (month < 10) {
            String finalMonth = "0" + month;
            finalFormat = year + "-" + finalMonth + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
        }

        return finalFormat;
    }

    public static String convertToLocalTime(String timeToConvert) {
        SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        sourceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(Constants.SERVER_TIME_ZONE));//where server time zone is the time zone of your server as defauul,E.X -America/Los_Angeles
        Date parsed;
        try {
            parsed = sourceFormat.parse(timeToConvert);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }

        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
        SimpleDateFormat destFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        destFormat.setTimeZone(tz);

        String result = destFormat.format(parsed);
        return result;
    }

    public static String getTimeZone() {
        return TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
    }
}
```